# Conditional random formulas

Tags: excel, random, conditional-statements, simulation

I'm working on developing a simulation model in Excel for a class project, and I have ran across this odd problem. My model is basically to simulate a tram path with multiple stations. To make it simpler, I have created this Excel sheet to demonstrate my model and issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qhD2.png

As you can see above, this is the information of riders who are arriving at station 1 and wanting to go to station 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

In the cells B3 to D3, I have this formula:

=ROUND(BETA.INV(RAND(), 4, 4, 0,6),0)

In the cell B4, I have this formula:

=IF($E$3>8,IF(B3=0,0,RANDBETWEEN(1,B3)),B3)

and finally, in the cells B6, I have:

=B3 - B4

Now, the tram capacity is only 8 riders at a time, so the total number in cell E4 cannot exceed 8. Is there a way I can tell Excel to do the following:

- If the total number of people in cell E3 is greater than 8, then randomly select numbers of riders who can get on the tram based on the number of riders who want to go to each station so long that the total number in cell E4 does NOT exceed 8 (just as demonstrated in the screenshot above).
- If the total number of people in cell E3 is less than or equal to 8, then the same number in cells B3 - D3 should carry over to cells B4 - D4.

Hopefully my explanation is clear enough. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think excel could do that as this involves recursive iteration. One workaround is you could generate lots of test case that try to form up the 8 if it is more than 8, then you can pick the success one as your answer.

You may take a look at my implementation. Here is the [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbyz60tnv79nwpj/Conditional%20random%20formulas%20in%20Excel.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Thank you Feng Hao for your answer. The only problem with this approach is that it will get more complicated as I expand the number of stations (I have 10) and the number of trains leaving each station (I have 4).

Comment: Then you could use VBA to do it.

Comment: Another problem I found with this approach is that if there is no test case that sums up to 8, the model crashes. How easy is it to create it using VBA? I have no experience with VBA whatsoever. Thanks Feng!

Comment: Yes. So the more the test cases the more likely it will success. If you know VB, then VBA is almost the same, if you know programming, then VBA is not hard to learn.

Comment: I will try learning VBA and hopefully I will get this figured out soon. Thanks Feng.